# Land to a specific folder in multi-lingual website without using meta refresh

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am creating a website which is in Japanese and English. The Public folder of my website has 2 folders /ja/... for japanese files and /en/... for english files. When the users come to the landing page I want them to automatically go to /ja/.. folder.

So, if user goes to www.example.com he should be automatically taken to www.example.com/ja.

One solution is to add index.html in Public folder and use Meta Refresh from there but it is said to be a bad practice. What should I do?

Comment: Do you have a http server like apache? And, does your website use any server side language like java, php... Or maybe it's just a completely static website.

Comment: Why are you not just putting the content in /ja/ into the public folder (in stead of having it in a /ja/), and only keep the /en/ for the English language? Then you don't have to redirect at all. - Else you can use a htaccess rule if you are on a Apache server.

Comment: @Wander, it has javascript, PHP. It is not static. The server is apache. Do you suggest .htaccess configuration? How?

Comment: I suggest using apache mod_rewrite module. In this way, request will be redirected before reaching your php web server. You can reference [apache document](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Answer (score 0):

I added this to my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mywebsite.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ ja [L]
```

Seems to work. But how is this better than meta refresh?

Comment: @Wander answered this in above comment.